# wait for http call service to recieve data in angular 7

Tags: angular, http, observable, response

I want bind data for mat-tree (angular material) dynamically. but my problem is that data source for the tree is undefined before getting actual data from http service which I've been implemented. I want to fill (dfns) to bind in mat-tree so to prevent getting [] data for it I decided to put (this.GetData) in  constructor class DynamicDatabase to get dfns data after calling initialData() but it didn't work too. i may use this.GetData in different times to get child nodes in my tree too. so please help me with it to get data for my tree in every where after http call returned data.  here is my code.

```
export class DynamicFlatNode {
constructor(
  public Title: string,
  public id: string,
  public PID: number,
  public Type: string,
  public s: string,
  public children: boolean,
  public level: number = 1,
  public expandable: boolean = false,
  public isLoading: boolean = false) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class DynamicDatabase {
  dfns: DynamicFlatNode[];
  Tempchilddfns: DynamicFlatNode[];

  public GetData(
    url: string,
    ptitle: string,
    parentnode: string,
    level: number,
  ): DynamicFlatNode[] {
    let Tempdfns: DynamicFlatNode[] = [];
    ptitle = ptitle != '' ? '?ptitle=' + ptitle : '';
    parentnode = parentnode != '' ? '?parent=' + parentnode : '';

    this.service.callservice('get', url + ptitle + parentnode, '').subscribe(
      resdata => {
        Tempdfns = resdata.map(
          ContentNode =>
            new DynamicFlatNode(
              ContentNode.Title,
              ContentNode.id,
              ContentNode.PID,
              ContentNode.Type,
              ContentNode.s,
              ContentNode.children,
              level,
              ContentNode.children,
            ),
        );
      },
      err => {
        alert(err.json());
      },
    );
    return Tempdfns;
  }

  constructor(private service: Service) {
    this.dfns = this.GetData('Subject/scripts/Subjectw.ashx', '', '', 0);
  }

  initialData(): DynamicFlatNode[] {
    return this.dfns;
  }

  getChildren(
    url: string,
    ptitle: string,
    parentnode: string,
    level: number,
  ): DynamicFlatNode[] | any {
    this.GetData(url, ptitle, parentnode, level + 1);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'Contenttree',
  templateUrl: './contenttree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contenttree.component.css'],
  providers: [DynamicDatabase],
})
export class ContenttreeComponent {
  constructor(database: DynamicDatabase) {
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode>(
      this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable,
    );
    this.dataSource = new DynamicDataSource(this.treeControl, database);

    this.dataSource.data = database.initialData();
  }

  dataSource: DynamicDataSource;
  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode>;
  getLevel = (node: DynamicFlatNode) => {
    return node.level;
  };
  isExpandable = (node: DynamicFlatNode) => {
    return node.expandable;
  };
  hasChild = (_: number, _nodeData: DynamicFlatNode) => {
    return;
    _nodeData.expandable;
  };
}
```

and also this this my general service to get data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  private BaseUrl: string = 'http://example/modul/';
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  callservice(method: string, serviceUrl: string, body: any) {
    let options = new RequestOptions();
    let URL = this.BaseUrl + serviceUrl;

    if (method == 'post')
      return this.http
        .post(URL, body, options)
        .pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
    if (method == 'get')
      return this.http
        .get(URL, options)
        .pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
    if (method == 'put')
      return this.http
        .put(URL, body, options)
        .pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's isn't a good practice to put logic inside the constructor, use ngOnInit lifecycle hook instead.

Comment: As written, `Service.callservice()` doesn't return anything, since all the returns are inside `if` logic.  For example, what would the function return if method == 'delete', or if method == undefined ...?  I would start by refactoring that function to always return an observable.

Comment: the problem solved using (promise) subject and after that using .then(......) which waits until getting data. thanks alot btw

Answer (score 0):

Even when you put your service call inside the constructor, since you are making an async request, you will always be gambling whether the call will be finished first or the template will be rendered.

The sequence will never be guaranteed.

If you want to not display the tree until the data is present, try controlling it like this:

```
<mat-tree *ngIf="dfns">
...
</mat-tree>
```

or like this:

```
<mat-tree *ngIf="dfns.length">
...
</mat-tree>
```

Comment: thanks but I can put my call service into initialData() but the whole idea is to get data after http call ends. I call  initialData() after that GetData() and finally callservice(). now i want to recursively get returned data back to its first place that called. how can i use promise according to my chain...?